# StackOverflowError While applying Alfresco Rule to convert Word Doc to PDF

Tags: pdf, alfresco, openoffice.org, libreoffice

I'm trying to target the following :

using the WebDav or throw the **Alfresco (Community): Current version 3.4.0 (d 3370) schema 4113** Admin interface, I'm trying to upload a Microsoft Office 2003/2007 or an OpenOffice/LibreOffice document into the Alfresco repository and with a rule associated to the node in question, convert the documents into a **PDFs** format.

The Alfresco instance is running on **WnXP**, LibreOffice is running as a headless instance on a **CentOS** 6.4

I followed the links cited here after to add OpenOffice support to my Alfresco instance but seems to don't work actually. I have an exception when the rule is trying to start.

**Links :**

```
http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Setting_up_OpenOffice_for_Alfresco
```

**Exception :**

```
ERROR;04/10/2012 16:48:55;;;[Utils];Failed to create content due to error: 09040000 Exception in Transaction.
org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 09040000 Exception in Transaction.
at org.alfresco.repo.transaction.RetryingTransactionHelper.doInTransaction(RetryingTransactionHelper.java:466)
at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.BaseDialogBean.finish(BaseDialogBean.java:124)
at org.alfresco.web.bean.dialog.DialogManager.finish(DialogManager.java:528)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.myfaces.el.MethodBindingImpl.invoke(MethodBindingImpl.java:132)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:61)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot._broadcastForPhase(UIViewRoot.java:97)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:171)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationExecutor.execute(InvokeApplicationExecutor.java:32)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.executePhase(LifecycleImpl.java:95)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:70)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.alfresco.web.app.servlet.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:104)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor416.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy232.doFilter(Unknown Source)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.BeanProxyFilter.doFilter(BeanProxyFilter.java:82)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.alfresco.repo.web.filter.beans.NullFilter.doFilter(NullFilter.java:68)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor416.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(ChainingSubsystemProxyFactory.java:116)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.transformedBeanName(AbstractBeanFactory.java:951)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:229)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:265)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1004)
at org.alfresco.repo.management.subsystems.SubsystemProxyFactory$1.invoke(SubsystemProxyFactory.java:69)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy98.isConnected(Unknown Source)
```

**My configuration :**
*tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco-global.properties*

```
module.id=org.alfresco.remoteOpenOffice
module.version=0.1
module.title=Remote OpenOffice
module.repo.version.min=2.2
ooo.host=192.168.14.67
ooo.port=8100
ooo.enabled=true
```

*tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/extension/remote-openoffice-context.xml*

```
<bean id="openOfficeConnection" class="net.sf.jooreports.openoffice.connection.SocketOpenOfficeConnection">
<constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="192.168.14.67"/>
<constructor-arg type="int" value="8100"/>
 </bean>
 <bean id="transformer.OpenOffice" class="org.alfresco.repo.content.transform.RemoteOpenOfficeContentTransformer" parent="baseContentTransformer" >
<property name="connection">
    <ref bean="openOfficeConnection" />
</property>
<property name="documentFormatsConfiguration">
    <value>classpath:alfresco/mimetype/openoffice-document-formats.xml</value>
</property>
 </bean>
```

and added *tomcat/shared/classes/alfresco/mimetype/openoffice-document-formats.xml*

there are no firewall between the Alfresco host and the openOffice host

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the full exception? Looks like you've only posted part of it

Comment: It's the only exception but it's repeated many times

Comment: The line before the ones starting "at ..." is important, it tells us what the exception is!

Comment: I just completed the stack as it happened that the appender was not correctly configured

Comment: There should be a "Caused by..." entry or two as well, which will show us why the transformation failed - that bit of the trace only tells us that it failed but not the cause of the failure

Comment: Also, are you sure that OO is listening on the correct port, on a suitable (non-loopback) address, and no firewalling could be getting in the way?

Comment: And here it is something is going wrong with my Log4J appender as well as console and it seems that's it's due to my machine which it's being slowed down by the anti virus.
So it seems that it's caused by a StackOverflowError appears at line 951 of this Class org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory, the parameter "name" of the method at that line at runetime is "extracter.worker.OpenOffice"

Here's my VM params :
-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -Xss96k -XX:MaxPermSize=256m

no firewall between the two machines.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17602/discussion-between-abderrazakk-and-gagravarr)

Answer (score 1):

`StackOverflowError` is normally caused by endless (or at least excessive) recursion. Since you mention a Rule, is it possible that the outcome of your Rule (e.g. modifying or creating a node) triggers the Rule again, causing an endless sequence?

What exactly is the Rule you are using? Does it trigger upon any mimetype, or just a Word document, for example?

Is there just a single Rule on that folder, or several?

Comment: thank's for your interest, actually there's only one rule called when ever I add an MSWord/2007 document. the node contains no document before the error is raised.